# Wordpress Navigation styling

Tags: html, css

Any idea why my navigation is messed up in any version < IE10 on the homepage, but looks fine on the post page?

http://www.craigwilliamson.info/wordpress/

Can't get my head round it works fine in all other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't put a closing tag on your `<h1>`

Never forget the `</h1>`!

To elaborate, the H1 styles are being applied further along the DOM due to the missing closing tag, but most modern browsers just bypass this. Still, it invalidates code so always remember it.

Comment: Well that was a rookie mistake hah! Thanks mate! Will choose this as answer in 8 mins ! :)

Comment: No problem, it's always the little things!